# VPS, Apache, Wordpress: The requested URL was not found для внутренних страниц сайта

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2, vps

Возникла задача перенести на другой VPS Wordpress-сайт (и ещё домен, но я сам не понимаю толком, что значит "перенести домен"). На Ubuntu 14.04 я подготовил Apache, MySQL и PhpMyAdmin, затем в `/var/www/html` загрузил wordpress-файлы уже существующего сайта через File Zilla.

Стартовая страница отображается корректно, но ко всем остальным доступа нет - показывает ошибку `The requested URL ... was not found on this server`. Возникает закономерный вопрос: а что, той маршрутизации, что встроена в Wordpress, недостаточно для того, чтобы корректно обрабатывать запросы? Это сообщение выглядит так, как будто Apache искал папку `/about` хотя её, естественно, нет.

Ссылки на сайте имеют абсолютный путь. То есть на `http://mywebsite/` отображение корректное, а, например, на `http://mywebsite/about` - уже ошибка.

В чём причина? Какие настройки я не сделал? Почему Wordpress не обрабатывает запросы корректно?

P. S. Я смотрел [вопрос-дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800933/the-requested-url-account-login-was-not-found-on-this-server), но ответов на него нет, поэтому создал новый вопрос и снабдил его подробным комментарием. Кроме того, я не уверен, что у Andrii из вопроса-дубликата та же причина, что и у меня.

Comment: *Ubuntu 14.04* — учитывая столь древнюю версию дистрибутива, для начала стоит сверить требования вашей версии *wordpress* с тем, что у вас сейчас в системе установлено.

Comment: С WordPress так нельзя. Почитайте, почему, и как надо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Comment: @KAGG Design, Благодарю Вас за ссылку на полезную информацию. Про сериализованные абсолютные ссылки я понял, но в моём случае домен остался тот же.

Comment: @alexander barakin, я за использование самых новых инструментов, но мне бы пошаговую инструкцию по настройке 18.04 или CentOS 7.5 с подробным объяснением, ЗАЧЕМ мы делаем то или иное дейтвие. Вот [лучшее](https://www.8host.com/blog/nachalnaya-nastrojka-servera-ubuntu-14-04/), что я видел, но оно для 14.04.

Comment: У вас путь к папкам на сервере изменился, насколько я понимаю. В этом случае тоже надо использовать плагин переноса.

Comment: Если нужна инструкция по настройке сервера, почитайте вот это: https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/. Там я писал для относительно опытных администраторов, но, думаю, разберётесь.

Comment: @KAGG Design, благодарю Вас за статью! Буду постепенно переходить на новейшую версию.

Comment: @KAGG Design, попробовал `All-in-One WP Migration` плагин. Ничего не изменилось - внутренние страницы сайта по-прежнему недоступны. Правда, доступна админ-панель.

Comment: Уже прогресс, значит, не зря применили плагин. А внутренние страницы недоступны, предположу, из-за .htaccess. Что у вас там?

Comment: @KAGG Design, не факт, что правильно, но решил проблему. Самого `.htaccess` у меня в папке `/var/www/html` сейчас нет. А заработало всё потому, что в `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` я указал `<Directory /var/www/html/> AllowOverride All</Directory>`.  Не знаю, так ли решается данная проблема, но редактировать файл `000-default.conf` всё равно нужно согласно некоторым публикациям.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79180/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).